# ASP.NET MVC 3 : How to turn determine Controller Action from Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Surprised I'm not finding this answer anywhere, how can I determine what Controller/Action will be invoked for a given URL in MVC 3?

## Update

What I really want to know:
"how can I determine what ControllerAction will be invoked for a given URL in MVC 3?" ....yeah

So, either I'm not aware of the magic method that does this:

`ControllerActionInfo GetControllerActionInfo(string url)`

Or, I will have to create it myself doing whatever MVC does when it gets an http request.

My purpose of asking about this on StackOverflow is that I can save some time reverse engineering this behavior. The correct answer should resemble:

`Here's how you can do it:` and some code would follow.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing the use case for this.  Typically from within the application, you're building the URL from the controller/action and letting the framework handle the routing. What need do you have to do the reverse?

Comment: The use case is top secret classified defcon 5.

Comment: The answer, then, is to iterate through the route collection until you find the first one that matches the HttpContext for the given url. The way to do that is classified top, top secret. :-)  Or you could look in the source, http://aspnet.codeplex.com.  I wouldn't expect the framework to expose this and I don't think it does.

Comment: Yes I could dig in the source. Even if I didn't have the source I could decompile. And so could every person that has ever asked a question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a dummy HttpContext and HttpRequest classes as follows:

```
public class DummyHttpRequest : HttpRequestBase {

    private string mUrl;

    public DummyHttpRequest(string url) {
        mUrl = url;
    }

    public override string AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath {
        get {
            return mUrl;
        }
    }

    public override string PathInfo {
        get {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

}

public class DummyHttpContext : HttpContextBase {

    private string mUrl;

    public DummyHttpContext(string url) {
        mUrl = url;
    }

    public override HttpRequestBase Request {
        get {
            return new DummyHttpRequest(mUrl);
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit:** Also, you can extend the `DefaultControllerFactory` and add a simple method to get the desired information instead of an instance of `Controller`. (*Note:* It's merely a sample, you have to support other aspects like `ActionNameAttribute` and so on)

```
public class ControllerActionInfo {

    public ControllerActionInfo(Type controllerType, MethodInfo action) {
        ControllerType = controllerType;
        Action = action;
    }

    public Type ControllerType { get; private set; }
    public MethodInfo Action { get; private set; }

}

public class DefaultControllerFactoryEx : DefaultControllerFactory {

    public ControllerActionInfo GetInfo(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName) {
        Type controllerType = GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);

        if (controllerType == null) {
            return null;
        }

        MethodInfo actionMethod = controllerType.GetMethod(requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action"), BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        return new ControllerActionInfo(controllerType, actionMethod);
    }

}
```

Then, use following code snippet to get access to the controller:

```
DummyHttpContext httpContext = new DummyHttpContext("~/home/index");
RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);
// IController controller = new DefaultControllerFactory().CreateController(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData), routeData.GetRequiredString("controller"));
DefaultControllerFactoryEx controllerFactory = new DefaultControllerFactoryEx();

var result = controllerFactory.GetInfo(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData), routeData.GetRequiredString("controller"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is much closer to what I need. But what about knowing which action will be executed?

Answer (score 0):

The logic for this is in the `System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler` class,  the `System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory` class, and the `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker` class.  [.NET Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) is your friend.

Basically, the MVC framework:

1. Uses reflection to get all the controllers in the application project.
2. Then it does something like `IEnumerable<string> controllerNames = controllerTypes.Select(controllerType => controllerType.Name.Replace("Controller",string.Empty));`.  It then tries to match the first path segment, `{controller}`, to one of these sanitized controller type names (case-insensitive).
3. Then, it looks at this controller's public methods that have a return type that is of type `ActionResult` or some derivative.    It matches the method name to the second path segment, `{action}`, as the action method to be called.
4. If the selected method has a parameter that is named `id`, then it matches the third path segment `{id}` to that value, and passes it to the method.  Otherwise, the optional `id` parameter is ignored.
5. If the `ActionResult` type that is returned is a derivative of `ViewResultBase` then the `IViewEngine` tries to locate a corresponding view in the project using whatever conventions have been specified for that view engine.  The `WebFormViewEngine`, for example, looks in the project for `~/Views/{controller}/{action}.ascx`,  `~/Views/{controller}/{action}.aspx`,  `~/Views/Shared/{action}.ascx`,  `~/Views/Shared/{action}.aspx` by default.

   - If you want to further understand how routing works in MVC, I would highly suggest [Scott Gu's article on MVC Routing](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx).

Comment: .net reflector is not my friend, anymore. Telerik JustDecompile is my new friend.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question. It just kind of tells what is happening given the DEFAULT ROUTE that comes in an mvc project.

Comment: @RonnieOverby, Your question was about MVC routing.  If you want further information about MVC routing specifically, you should check the Scott Gu link at the end of my answer.  If your question is about how Microsoft's routing in general works, then you should specify that.  My answer illustrates the pattern that is used, and how it is applied by default in MVC.  I'm not sure what else you want

Comment: @RonnieOverby, you may want to check out this 4guysfromrolla article, [Using ASP.NET Routing Without ASP.NET MVC](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx) for help getting an understanding of the fundamentals of ASP.NET routing, independently of the ASP.NET **MVC** framework.  The only specific different between routing in general and MVC routing, is that MVC will throw an exception if the `{controller}` and `{action}` route parameters are not both defined.  (They can be defined implicitly by setting a default value)