# Determining the controller from a raw URL in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Given the following URL: http://www.domain.com/Client

is it possible to access the Route Data in a controller to determine which Controller/Action that is bound to?

Comment: You can but it completely depends on where you want to access that data from..controller, authorize attribute, global.asax file...?

Comment: In a controller - question updated.

Comment: Ok, so I have got to ask...if you are in a controller...wouldn't you already know what controller you are in?  Just trying to understand the logic you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, because it's a partial action for my navigation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 3 : How to turn determine Controller Action from Url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112748/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-turn-determine-controller-action-from-url)

Comment: I found the above that speaks to what you are trying to do.  You will need to replace the fully qualified URL that you are trying to trace back to just a relative URL though

Comment: You should post as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: Mike, I posted as an answer below - sorry about the close vote, I have been chastised for not identifying possible duplicates when answering before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pretty simple to determine the controller from the RouteData dictionary, passing the key that you are looking for.

```
namespace UI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var controllerName = RouteData.Values["controller"];
            //controllerName == "Home" at this point
            var actionName = RouteData.Values["action"];
            //actionName == "Index" at this point         
            return View("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have found some information regarding how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112748/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-turn-determine-controller-action-from-url): but, you will need to change your absolute URLs back to relative URLs before you can run them through the solution provided.

Comment: This shows the route for the current request. I need to lookup a URL.